# How can I limit my Google chart to 7 items?

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm wondering how I could limit the MAX amount of items it can display to my chart to 5. I've got a cron job updating the .json daily, and currently it just tries to fit them all onto there.

This is my code:

```js
<script>
google.charts.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
 var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/server/database.json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

 var options = {
  title: 'Players Hourly',
  'is3D':true,
  legend: 'bottom',
  hAxis: { 
   minValue: 0,
   format: 'long'
  },
  vAxis: {
   minValue: 0,
         scaleType: 'log',
         format: 'long'
    },
  pointSize: 5,
        series: {
            0: { pointShape: 'circle' },
        } 
 };
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('serverstats'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
}
$(window).resize(function(){
 drawChart();
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy way would be to use a data view and the `setRows` method.
then use the view to draw the chart.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);  //<-- provide an array of the row indexes you want to see
...
chart.draw(view, options);  //<-- use view here
```

**EDIT**

to show the last 5 rows...

```
  var viewRows = [];
  for (var i = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; i > data.getNumberOfRows() - 6; i--) {
    viewRows.push(i);
  }
  view.setRows(viewRows);
```

Comment: This does work, but only applies the first 5 indexes. I want to see the last 5 at all times. Thanks for the help already. @WhiteHat

Comment: Umm, I just figured our that your solution shows the last 5 rows, but shows them backwards. The first last one comes upfront and the 5th one comes at the end. Making it look like progress is going down if you see what I mean. Any way around this? Appreciate the help so far.

Comment: Never mind, direction: '-1', did the job. Thanks a lot.